# Chamar JavaScript dentro do Modal

Tags: javascript, modal

É possível obter um resultado de uma função JavaScript e jogar este resultado dentro de uma Modal?

Tenho esta função:

```
<script>

$('#download').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('xxxx').disabled=false
    document.getElementById('xxxx').disabled=false

    var formData = $(document.forms[0]).serialize().split('&').join('\n');


    this.href = 'data: ,' +  formData ;




    document.getElementById('xxxx').disabled=true
    document.getElementById('xxxxx').disabled=true

});

</script>
```

O Resultado "formData" teria que ser jogado dentro de um Popup modal. Código dele:

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" >Clique aqui para ver a janela</a>
   <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Atenção!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar tudo</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Caros; peço qie desconsiderem a pergunta acima, a mesma foi "picotada".

Comment: O que você quer dizer com picotada? Ninguem alterou nada na pergunta, apenas houve uma formatação de código e melhoramento do titulo. Se está picotada também você pode edita-la e adicionar mais informações.

Comment: Pensei que ela n tinha ido formatado e que iria ficar confuso. Foi minha primeira interação a este forum. Grato.

Comment: este não é um fórum, é um [Q&A](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), só pra deixar claro a diferença. Você pode editar a pergunta quantas vezes quiser e se não tiver respostas,você pode apagá-la também.

Comment: Grato pela resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caros;

Resolvi meu problema com o código abaixo:

```
function copy_form()
    {
id('modalxxx').value = id('xxx').value;
id('modalyyy').value = id('yyy').value;
id('modalrrr').value = id('rrr').value;
id('modalttt').value = id('ttt').value;


    }

 function id( el ){
  return document.getElementById( el );
                  }
    window.onload = function()
       {
    id('btnenviar').onclick = function()
       }
    copy_form();
      }
   }

</script>
```

Agradeço pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode dar um ID para a div que vai receber o conteudo

```
<div class="modal-body" id="conteudoModal">
```

E então depois do form data

```
var formData = $(document.forms[0]).serialize().split('&').join('\n');
document.getElementById('conteudoModal').innerHTML(formData);
```

Seria isso?